# Need examples for creating user reviews in Java/Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I need to create customer reviews in Play Framework.

Like
1. A form for the user to write a review (Possibly with Captcha).
2. Show the current reviews for a particular product, When user visits the product page.

I could find lot of PHP based solutions to the above problem, But not so much for Java/Play Framework.

What i need is some Java based examples on how to implement customer reviews. Anything particular to Play! Framework will be much appreciated!

Comment: You should refactor your question or it will be closed soon

Comment: @biesior, Thanks! i updated my question. Please let me know if i need to provide more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you will not find such ready-to-use solution as Play is a framework not a CMS... sorry.

You also should NOT for Java samples how to do that as each framework has it's own set of tools and sometimes the same things requires quite different approach.

Instead you should start by learning... the Play. Your case is really easy, and you should be able to write it basing on the official [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/JavaHome) and/or [samples](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/master/samples/java), check `computer-database` and `forms` for an instance.

In very general ***product*** with ***reviews*** will be quite similar to any blog with ***post*** and ***comments*** so maybe some [video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL09AA9DE05DEEF70C) will help you to get the concept.

That's really easy ;]

Comment: The video tutorial is so helpful! and i started liking the simplicity of Play! Framework .. Thank you so much :)